# Rails app behaves differently on heroku vs development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, pg, sqlite3-ruby

In Application Controller I have 2 methods :

```
 def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token( cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
 end
 helper_method :current_user

 def pro_user
  @pro_user = Subscription.where(:email => current_user.email).pluck(:email) if current_user
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
helper_method :pro_user
```

Current user's email is inserted into Subscription table after payment is completed. So I check if the user is a paid user by looking up the current_user.email in Subscription.

On the View I block this accordingly for pro vs non pro users.

```
  <% if current_user %>
        <!-- logged in -->      
       <% if pro_user.empty? %>             
               <!-- Not a premium user -->

        <!--Display some html that iss free but not premium content -->

       <% else %> 

            <!-- This is a  premium user  -->
                 <!-- Display all html accordingly -->

       <% end %>     


   <% else %> 
              <!-- Not logged in-->

         <!-- Display html  message to log in -->
   <% end %>
```

Everything works properly on my development machine which has sqlite3 db. But on pushing to heroku, a premium user is never recognized. Basically I think if pro_user.empty? does not work as expected. Any help is appreciated. Could there be rails differences in the return value of empty? method between sqlite3 and pg dbs? I have done pg:reset a few times.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely problems with using different dbs in development and production environment. Queries and ORM could work differently between sqlite and postgres. Therefore, I recommend using actual local postgreSQL if you are using that on heroku. Installation is really simple. Just go to the link I provide and install.

[Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/)

Comment: I guess so. I think this line is not translated differently for postgres.  Subscription.where(:email => current_user.email).pluck(:email)